# Как посмотреть коммиты в гите с помощью Python?

Tags: python, git

Как посмотреть все коммиты в репозитории?

Есть такой скрипт:

```
from github import Github

g = Github("log", "pass")
branch = g.get_repo("repo").get_branch("master")
result = branch.commit
print(result, branch.commit.author.created_at)
```

Я только могу увидеть последний коммит. А как их все вывести?

Comment: Как устанавливали пакет github? `pip install github` пишет что нет такого пакета.

Comment: Я тоже с этим мучался. Пакет называется pygithub

Answer (score 2):

```
from github import Github

g = Github()  # возможен анонимный доступ, но с ограниченным количеством запросов
repo = g.get_repo('git/git')  # 'пользователь/репозиторий'
for commit in repo.get_commits():
    print(commit.sha, commit.author, commit.last_modified)
```

Кстати, `commit.author.created_at` даст вам не дату коммита, а дату регистрации пользователя.

Comment: Спасибо добрый человек